# horizontal scroll behaviour in vue.js on anchor link click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working in vue frame work.I have an issue with scroll behavior , whenever clicking the  side menu .
In my web application I have side navigation bar towards left side of the screen and the corresponding content panel in the middle of the page . you can check the image i have added.

so whenever i click the side menu , it reaches to the corresponding panel.

The vertical scroll bar is working fine , but I have issues with horizontal scroll bar.

The horizontal scroll bar gets scrolled bit towards middle of the page.

expected behavior

whenever i click. The horizontal scroll should remain always in the left ,

my current code

```
       scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
   if (to.hash) {
     return { selector: to.hash };

   } else if (savedPosition) {
     return savedPosition;
   }
   return { x: 0, y: 0 };
 },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the function of `scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition)` could be helpful.

Comment: i already i have something like this ''' scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash };
    } else if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    }
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },

Comment: it did not work ?  you can debugger whether it works or not

Comment: actually the method is called when debugging , but i guess i should change the condition . Because if (to.hash) { it returns the coresponding hash section but its not calling x=0, y=0 .either i can add this return statement to it. but i guess can we combine both in one codition

Comment: I have an idea.you can force the window scrollLeft to be 0 after the window mounted .Maybe 'setTimeout' can be work.

Comment: setTimeout(() => this.scrollFix(this.$route.hash), 1);   is this wat you meant?

Comment: setTimeout(()=> {$selector.scrollLeft(0)}, 0)

Comment: i got fixed posted the answer above

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (to.hash) {
  return {
    selector: to.hash,
    offset: { x: the main content  element value in my case it was 204.2,  y:0 },
  };
  } else if (savedPosition) {
   return savedPosition;
  }
  return { x: 0, y: 0 };
 },
```

it worked